# Place 'selected' attribute in matching option (in directive)

Tags: angularjs

How do I go about placing the 'selected' attribute in the `option` where `device.type`s value is equivalent to. For some weird reason, the first `option` gets displayed even though `device.type` is of some other value. Where's the best place to put the code in the directive, `link`, `compile`, or `controller`?

template.html

```
<div>

    <select ng-model="device.type">
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
        <option value="value2" selected>value2</option>
        .
        .
        .
        <option value="valueN">valueN</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

directive

```
app.directive('details', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            device: '=',
            ...
        },
        templateUrl : 'template.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // put 'selected' on option element where device.type is equivalent to
            // is it preferrable to put logic here? or in controller or compile
        }
    };
});
```

Appreciate your inputs. Thanks.

Comment: change to `ng-model="device.type"` - i.e. remove the `{{ }}`. You need to pass the scope property itself, not an expression.

Comment: @NewDev I already removed the {{}}. Problem still persisting though.

Comment: You don't actually need the `selected` attribute - just set your `device.type` to whatever you want the value to be set to.

Comment: @NewDev `device.type` has already an initial value pulled from the backend.  So if I want to edit that, the `option` appearing/selected should be the initial value.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of this along with some data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a directive to achieve that.
Just fill you select with `ng-options` and use `track by <some field>`.
Then, when your select's model changes, it will select the right option corresponding to the field you choose in `track by <some field>`.

Something like that :

```
<select 
    ng-model="device"
    ng-options="device as device.type for device in devices track by device.type">
</select>
```

So, when you put a device object in the select's model, it will select the option with the `device.type` matching your model.